# Speeding up selenium tests

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, nightwatch.js

I run selenium by doing:

```
java -jar /opt/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.args="--use-gl=osmesa" -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/bin/chromedriver -Dwebdriver.chrome.bin=/usr/bin/google-chrome  -log /home/jenkins-user/log/selenium.log &
```

Then I run the nightwatch selenium tests. For some reason, it takes 20 minutes for the full test suite to run. Is there anything I can do to speed it up? Maybe some configuration I can pass in to java?

Comment: And you think 20 minutes is too long? Why? What's your expectation, what are these tests doing?

Answer (score 0):

I have a dual Selenium environment setup with Firefox as the default webdriver and Phantomjs as an alternate environment.  When I'm writing tests, I use the firefox driver and watch what breaks through the browser.  But for the CI server, I use phantomjs which doesn't actually open browser windows.  I haven't actually timed it, but it's probably about 50% faster.

I always start the Selenium server with the following, no matter what tests I want to run:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -Dphantomjs.binary.path=../bin/phantomjs
```

code.suite.yml contains the following:

```
class_name: CodeTester
modules:
    enabled:
         - WebDriver:
         - Db:
            cleanup: false
    config:
         WebDriver:
            url: 'http://my.example.com'
            browser: firefox
            clear_cookies: true
            window_size: 1024x768
            capabilities:
                unexpectedAlertBehaviour: 'accept'

env:
    phantom:
        modules:
            config:
                WebDriver:
                    browser: phantomjs
                    clear_cookies: true
                    window_size: 1024x768
                    capabilities:
                        unexpectedAlertBehaviour: 'accept'
                        phantomjs.cli.args: [ '--ignore-ssl-errors=true' ]
```

To invoke the default Firefox, I just run the following (no env supplied):

```
php codecept.phar run gui --steps
```

But to specify the phantomjs env, I execute the following:

```
php codecept.phar run code --steps --env phantom
```

Answer (score 0):

If 20 minutes it too long, try to run your test parallel on one machine or use selenium hub to run test parallel on multiple machines. 
Check the section about `workers` here http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#parallel-running